# Spinner с заполнением из базы данных

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь в spinner засунуть названия строчек из Базы данных, но надо сделать так, чтобы когда в базе данных добавлялись элементы - их тоже можна было выбрать.
Вот как я это пробую делать (не добавляет ничего):

```
   int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        //Формируете список операторов, которые будут в спинере
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.shablspin);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameColIndex);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        c.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }
```

DBHelper.class

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            // конструктор суперкласса
            super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
            // создаем таблицу с полями
            db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                    + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + "name text,"
                    + "ip1 text,"
                    + "socket1 text,"
                    + "ip2 text,"
                    + "socket2 text,"
                    + "apn text,"
                    + "gprs text" + ");");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно какими данными вы хотите заполнить выпадающий список? В конструктор адаптера видимо и следует передать массив или контейнер с названиями строчек из БД

Comment: Вот моя база данных: оттуда надо надо выдернуть "name", и вставить его в Spinner

Comment: С помощью метода "getColumnIndex("name")" вы получаете номер колонки в таблице, у которой имя name, в вашем случае метод вернул  nameColIndex  = 1 (так как счет начинается с нуля). Вопрос, что вы с этим числом хотите далее сделать?

Comment: я понимаю что это не подходит, и поэтому и спрашиваю что делать... Так делал с отправкой в смс, уже понял с ваших слов как это работает... Но вопрос с выборкой для спиннера остается открытым

Comment: То есть насколько я понял в выпадающем списке должен быть список: id, name, ip1, ... и так далее?

Comment: Нет, только пункт name, по нему уже будет идти выборка из этой БД для отправки в sms ip1,socket1,ip2 и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первую очередь , раз вы собрались работать с БД , то логично использовать `SimpleCursorAdapter` или собственный на его основе ,который работает напрямую с курсором и не требует бессмысленной перегонки данных в какие то временные хранилища , вроде коллекции .

Далее , выборка из БД осуществляется следующим образом :

```
database = DBhelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.query("mytable", new String[]{"_id", "name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

где:
 `mytable` - имя таблицы , из которой необходимо сделать выборку
 `name` - поле (столбец) в таблице , из которого необходимо получить значения
 `_id` - необходимо для корректной работы в адаптере , поле (столбец) должен присутствовать в таблице. Значение - ID записи

Далее мы передаем полученный курсор в адаптер и привязываем его к спиннеру .

```
mSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.shablspin);
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, сursor, new String[] {"name"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Для обновления данных в спиннере, необходимо заново сделать выборку из БД в курсор , чтобы получить актуальные данные , затем сделать `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Узнать больше о работе с БД вы можете из [этой статьи](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/database.php) , там же есть альтернативный вариант спиннера с заполнением из БД , использующий промежуточный массив.

[Пример](http://droidtips.ru/zapolnenie-spinner-iz-bazy-dannykh-cherez-cursor-loader/) более правильной реализации этой задачи через `CursorLoader` , который управляет жизненным циклом курсора и загружает данные в фоне.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: ,изза чего может подчеркивать данные после db.query (проблема в поле name)

Comment: да , поправил еще